# Send perforce commit mail only to users who are allowed to see changelist

Tags: perforce

We are using a perforce setup where different teams have different access privileges to paths in the depot.

Now we would like to use a script along the lines of the python scripts at http://wiki.workshop.perforce.com/wiki/P4Review to send commit mails to users who have subscribed for changes in certain paths.

We want to use a central service for sending these mails using an account which has the privileges to view the changelists submitted by all developers.

The p4review.py script uses the `p4 reviews` command to figure out who has subscribed to which depot path. Unfortunately this command seems not to consider if the user who subscribed to commits in a certain path is actually allowed to see changelist contents (i.e. the names of the files submitted).

We checked by subscribing a user to a path (with `p4 user` in the `reviews` section), such as `//depot1/path1/...` and then revoked all privileges for that user.
Then we searched for a changelist which changes something below `//depot1/path1` and called `p4 reviews -c <changelist>` for it. The user was still listed as reviewer of this changelist.

So what is preferred way to make sure that developers will receive commit mail only for changes they are actually permitted to see?

Perforce server version is 2011.1.

Answer (score 0):

If the account you're using to run the review daemon is also a super user, you can use `p4 protects -u username filename` for each of the files in the changelist to determine whether the user has rights to see those files.  If they don't, this will return nothing, and you can skip sending them mail.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it is not an option for us to run the daemon with privileges beyond seeing what it needs to see.

Comment: I suspect you're out of luck, then.  The daemon won't be able to determine who to send mail to if it can't tell what a given user has access to.